# How to open more than one link in a tab

Tags: c#

I'm making some kind of web opener.

So basically if you type a link e.g. www.google.com/123456 , it will delete the last two characters and should add new ones ( I need to implement this).

My problem right now is, I can't open any link at all.

I've seen on stackoverflow people are using `Process.Start()` , so I've tried it but it says that, the system can't find the file specified.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Type your link here: ");
    string url = Console.ReadLine();
    url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 2);

    GoToSite(url);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void GoToSite(string url)
{
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

I expect to open the link, and the if the input is www.google.com/123, the output should be www.google.com/1

Comment: Try adding `https://` and/or `www` to make sure that the system interprets the string as an url.

Comment: Already tried, same error

Comment: Have you set a default web browser in your OS?

Comment: Yes it's Chrome

Comment: Could you give me an example input that is not working?

Comment: ``https://www.google.com/123`` , when im debugging the output is ``www.google.com/1``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195979/discussion-between-nico-schreiner-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.Start(string url)` works differently on .NET Core than on .NET Framework.

For .NET Core you need to do it like this:

```
public static void GoToSite(string url)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(url);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            url = url.Replace("&", "^&");
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = true });
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
        }
        else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://brockallen.com/2016/09/24/process-start-for-urls-on-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for?

make sure you have chrome installed, and In global os(windows) path var full path of chrome is setup.

then you simply call `Process.Start("chrome.exe")` which starts google chrome.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Type your link here: ");
    string url = Console.ReadLine();    
    url = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 3);
    GoToSite(url);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void GoToSite(string url)
{
      string chromeArgs = $"--new-window {url}";
      Process.Start("chrome.exe", chromeArgs);  
}
```

Comment: where should I put the full path ?

Comment: when you install google chrome, chrome installer will add that to your OS by default. In case if it gives you  any kinda of process.start exception make sure the path is set.